# How to pass argument to ASP.NET MVC 3 controller that is called via onclick attribute of a html button?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following View code (ASP:NET MVC 3):

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            City
        </th>
        <th>
            Hotel
        </th>
        <th>
            Room name
        </th>
        <th>
            Number of beds
        </th>
        <th>
            Price per night
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x=>Model.SelectedRoom.Hotel.City.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.SelectedRoom.Hotel.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.SelectedRoom.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.SelectedRoom.NumberOfBeds)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.SelectedRoom.PricePerNight)
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
            <input type="hidden" name="RoomID" value="@Model.SelectedRoom.RoomID" id="RoomID" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <p>
                From: @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.DateOne, new {@class="datepicker1", @readonly="readonly" }) 
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.DateOne)

                To: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateTwo, new { @class = "datepicker2", @readonly = "readonly" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.DateTwo)

            </p>
            <p>
                Total cost : @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.TotalCost, new {@class="TotalAmount", @readonly="readonly" })
            </p>
              <br />
           <input type="button" id="Reserve" value="Confirm" onclick = "window.location.href='/Home/MakeReservation'+@Model" />
    }
```

Here is my Model definition for this View:

```
public class MakeReservationViewModel
    {
        BusinessLogic bl;

        public MakeReservationViewModel() 
        {
            bl = new BusinessLogic();
        }

        public Room SelectedRoom { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please select a starting date")]
        public DateTime DateOne { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select an ending date")]  
        public DateTime DateTwo { get; set; }

        public decimal TotalCost { get; set; }
    }
```

**How to call **MakeReservation*** controller action from above View by clicking on a button and setting it's onclick attribut to MakeReservation properly?*
Here is my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ViewResult MakeReservation(MakeReservationViewModel mrvm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }

        return View();
    }
```

This is the error I ger:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
on this line:

**How to make model accept hidden field?**

SOLVED.
I added :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedRoom.RoomID, new {@class="RoomID", @hidden="hidden" })
```

instead of previous way that used not strongly typed property.

Comment: But why are you doing it that way?  Why aren't you using a normal submit button and the conventional form posting mechanics?

Comment: How do you mean not conventional?

Comment: `<form action="@Url.Action("MakeReservation")" method="POST">...<input type="submit" value="Submit Form" /></form>`   i.e.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_(HTML)

Comment: You are wright, I deleted the argument and is working.

Comment: But now it doesn't pass validation as it gets 0 for TotalCost of Model property in the controller.

Comment: Yes, because you are not using forms as they are supposed to be used.  You should read up on that wikipedia article so you have a sound foundation for how this is all supposed to come together.